# função para diminuir e aumentar o volume (audio HTML5)

Tags: javascript

Olá, tenho uma função que diminui e aumenta  o volume da música, só que estou com problema, o mouse não acompanha o `span` que faz a função para aumentar e diminuir o volume, por exemplo eu clico e seguro o mouse em cima da `span`, só que em vez de ele se mover tanto para direita quando para esquerda, ele só move depois que o mouse sai de cima dele e quando a seta do mouse está quase saindo da tela (se é que me entendem), aqui esta a função

```
var player,drag;
var audioElement,playButton,slider,audioButton,icoAudio;

function selectPlayer(elem){

     if(player!=elem){
        player=elem;
     }

     audioElement=player.querySelector('audio');
     playButton=player.querySelector('.play');
     slider=player.querySelector('.slider');
     sliderVol=slider.querySelector('.bar');
     audioButton=player.querySelector('.audio');
     playButton.addEventListener('click',playAudio);
     slider.addEventListener('mousedown', startDrag);
     slider.addEventListener('mousemove',showVolume);
     sliderVol.addEventListener('mousemove',showVolume);
     slider.addEventListener('mouseup', startDrag);
     sliderVol.addEventListener('mouseup', startDrag);
     sliderVol.querySelector('span').addEventListener('mouseup', startDrag);
     document.addEventListener('mouseup', startDrag);
}

function startDrag(event){

   if(event.type=="mousedown"){
     drag=true;
   }else{
     drag=false;
   }

}

function showVolume(event){

    if(drag){
       var w=slider.clientWidth;
       var x=(event.clientX)-slider.offsetLeft;
       var pctVol=x/w;

       if(pctVol>1){
         sliderVol.style.width=100+"%";
         audioElement.volume=1;
       }else if(pctVol<0){
         sliderVol.style.width=0+"%";
         audioElement.volume=0;
       }else{
         sliderVol.style.width=(x/w)*100+"%";
         audioElement.volume=pctVol;
      }

   }

}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="slider absolute">
   <div class="back relative">
      <div class="bar relative"><span class="right"></span></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.slider{
        top:85px;
        left:10px;
        padding:0 0 0 60px;
        width:425px;
        height:75px;
        box-sizing:border-box;
    }
    .slider .back {
        margin:11px 0 0 -60px;
        padding:7px 7px;
        width:425px;
        height: 55px;
        box-sizing:border-box;
    }
    .slider .bar {
        width:100%;
        height: 41px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        background-color: #0A35A1;
        border-radius:4px;
        box-shadow:0 0 2px 2px #000;
    }
    .slider .bar span {
        position: relative;
        top: -13px;
        right: -6px;
        width: 70px;
        height: 70px;
        cursor:pointer;box-sizing: border-box; background-color: #0A35A1;-webkit-border-radius: 50%; -moz-border-radius: 50%;border-radius: 50%;box-shadow:0 0 2px 2px #000;}
```

Comment: muda o evento `mouseup` para `mousedown`

Comment: Com o código postado não é possível reproduzir o problema. Você deve colocar um exemplo fornecendo todas as partes necessárias para se reproduzir o problema. Qualquer duvida consulte https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve